Life on a planet orbiting a pulsar
I’m trying to create a species for my sci-fi series that comes from a planet orbiting a pulsar. What would be needed for life to exist, and if it could, what would it look like?

We can't say what the lifeforms would look like... that's your decision based upon the things that the lifeforms would need to do to live there.  We also don't know if the planet is orbiting in the plane of the pulsar emissions or at some angle to it.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As far as I can tell the answer is maybe with caveats or no.
Here are two sources on it (the quora one is a summary of the space.com article)
https://www.quora.com/Do-any-planets-around-Pulsar-stars-support-life-If-so-how-does-that-life-survive
https://www.space.com/39157-deadly-pulsars-could-host-habitable-planets.html
Pulsars emit very high levels of radiation. Mostly in one direction (I'm pretty sure any planet going through the discharge cones would get its atmosphere blasted off pretty quick and would get toasted) but also ambiently in all directions.
If we're just talking any sort of life form though its possible certain small organisms (like tardigrades and some microbes) could survive with very little protection in bodies of water or underground.
If we're talking humans however it would be unlikely for life to persist on the surface. Possibly with a very thick atmosphere it would work. At least Alessandro Patruno, an astrophysicist at Leiden University in the Netherlands thinks its entirely possible that some kind of super earth with a thick atmosphere could make it work.
Its also entirely possible that at least for most neutron stars that the surrounding space is too inhospitable for humans to survive naturally. That said maybe some orbital sci fi constructs, insulated bunkers, or space magic could make this possible even if most of the time it wouldn't be practical naturally.
Edit: As for just straight up human sized aliens I suppose its impossible to be sure given we dont know the limits of evolution. I assume they will still need an atmosphere though and liquid water so even if they are born with enhanced radiation resistance the planet will still need higher gravity and a denser atmosphere to prevent the atmosphere from being stripped and the majority liquid water from being evaporated away.

Here is another link for your excellent answer https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_neutron_star_systems also note that the question is tagged for hard science, so no "space magic"

Since you haven’t specified humanoid or land-dwelling life, the Europa option is your best bet. An icy planet (heated by its own radioactivity) or moon (heated by tidal flexing), with a deep ocean of liquid water under many kilometres of ice, which is an excellent radiation shield. It doesn’t matter if the atmosphere is blown away by the radiation from the pulsar, because there’s no life anywhere near the surface anyway. That could be very hospitable to aquatic life, and it may well be that most life in the universe is in similar environments (though mostly not in the same solar system as a pulsar). It would be very hard for intelligent life forms to get into space, and pretty hard for them to even discover that space exists, but you’ve not specified that as a requirement either.
